# How do goroutines work? (or: goroutines and OS threads relation)

Tags: concurrency, go, goroutine

How can other goroutines keep executing whilst invoking a syscall? (when using GOMAXPROCS=1)
As far as I'm aware of, when invoking a syscall the thread gives up control until the syscall returns.
How can Go achieve this concurrency without creating a system thread per blocking-on-syscall goroutine?

From the [documentation](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#goroutines):

> Goroutines
>
> They're called goroutines because the existing terms—threads,
>   coroutines, processes, and so on—convey inaccurate connotations. A
>   goroutine has a simple model: it is a function executing concurrently
>   with other goroutines in the same address space. It is lightweight,
>   costing little more than the allocation of stack space. And the stacks
>   start small, so they are cheap, and grow by allocating (and freeing)
>   heap storage as required.
>
> Goroutines are multiplexed onto multiple OS threads so if one should
>   block, such as while waiting for I/O, others continue to run. Their
>   design hides many of the complexities of thread creation and
>   management.

Comment: This blog post by Dave Cheney's REALLY explains https://dave.cheney.net/2015/08/08/performance-without-the-event-loop

Comment: Related, and includes some diagrams from newer Go scheduler: [What is relationship between goroutine and thread in kernel and user state](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48638663/1256452)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If a goroutine is blocking, the runtime will start a new OS thread to handle the other goroutines until the blocking one stops blocking.

Reference : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/2IdA34yR8gQ

Comment: It actually multiplexes different goroutines into threads (1+ goroutine per thread). If one blocks, another one is switched to run on the same thread. This operation only needs 3 registers to change, thats why its so light.

Answer (score 36):

Ok, so here's what I've learned:
When you're doing raw syscalls, Go indeed creates a thread per blocking goroutine. For example, consider the following code:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "syscall"
)

func block(c chan bool) {
        fmt.Println("block() enter")
        buf := make([]byte, 1024)
        _, _ = syscall.Read(0, buf) // block on doing an unbuffered read on STDIN
        fmt.Println("block() exit")
        c <- true // main() we're done
}

func main() {
        c := make(chan bool)
        for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
                go block(c)
        }
        for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
                _ = <-c
        }
}
```

When running it, Ubuntu 12.04 reported 1004 threads for that process.

On the other hand, when utilizing Go's HTTP server and opening 1000 sockets to it, only 4 operating system threads were created:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "net/http"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi there, I love %s!", r.URL.Path[1:])
}

func main() {
        http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
        http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

So, it's a mix between an IOLoop and a thread per blocking system call.

Comment: it uses native epoll (or the alterntive on other systems) for sockets, doesn't use it for file io, there was a discussion about it somewhere on the mailing list.

Comment: Go runtime has a thing called network poller https://golang.org/src/runtime/netpoll.go It uses non blocking native APIs available on the target OS to handle network IO so that you could have thouthands of goroutines all using network IO.

Comment: Non-blocking I/O isn't anything new. Node.js or Java NIO or many other languages support it by leveraging those calls provided by the OS.

Comment: @creker yes, in the http server example(above) only 4 OS threads amidst working with netpoller

Comment: In the first case(`syscall.Read()`),Does it make sense for Go programm to create a thread pool of OS threads(at one go), in order to avoid thread creation time(after syscall is blocked)

Answer (score 22):

It can't. There's only 1 goroutine that can be running at a time when GOMAXPROCS=1, whether that one goroutine is doing a system call or something else.

However, most blocking system calls, such as socket I/O, waiting for a timer are not blocked on a system call when performed from Go. They're multiplexed by the Go runtime onto epoll, kqueue or similar facilities the OS provides for multiplexing I/O.

For other kinds of blocking system calls that cannot be multiplexed with something like epoll, Go does spawn a new OS thread, regardless of the GOMAXPROCS setting (albeit that was the state in Go 1.1, I'm not sure if the situation is changed)

Comment: I don't see any reason for a down vote. This answer sums it up quite nicely.

Comment: That because `GOMAXPROCS` doesn't handle the number of goroutines that can be runing. At least, not in the context of the question. And the `GOMAXPROCS` doesn't prevent go to create more threads. It just prevent it to execute them on multiple processors…

Comment: @Elwinar `GOMAXPROCS` sets the number of system threads that run Go code simultaneously. Since every go code is associated with a goroutine, this effectively limits the number of simultaneously running go routines. Also, nos explains pretty well that there can be *more than one* system thread, even if `GOMAXPROCS` is 1. Also, processors have nothing to do with this.

Comment: This answer helped me understanding there *is* an IOLoop, but that wasn't the question so I didn't accept it. Upvoted anyways :) Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You have to differentiate processor number and thread number: you can have more threads than physical processors, so a multi-thread process can still execute on a single core processor.

As the documentation you quoted explain, a goroutine isn't a thread: it's merely a function executed in a thread that is dedicated a chunk of stack space. If your process have more than one thread, this function can be executed by either thread. So a goroutine that is blocking for a reason or another (syscall, I/O, synchronization) can be let in its thread while other routines can be executed by another.

Answer (score 6):

I’ve written an article explaining how they work with examples and diagrams. Please feel free to take a look at it here: https://osmh.dev/posts/goroutines-under-the-hood

Answer (score 2):

From documentation of [runtime](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/):

> The GOMAXPROCS variable limits the number of operating system threads that can execute user-level Go code simultaneously. There is no limit to the number of threads that can be blocked in system calls on behalf of Go code; those do not count against the GOMAXPROCS limit.

so when one OS thread is blocked for syscall, another thread can be started - and `GOMAXPROCS = 1` is still satisfied. The two threads are NOT running simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this example of sum numbers helps you.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func put(number chan<- int, count int) {
    i := 0
    for ; i <= (5 * count); i++ {
        number <- i
    }
    number <- -1
}

func subs(number chan<- int) {
    i := 10
    for ; i <= 19; i++ {
        number <- i
    }
}

func main() {
    channel1 := make(chan int)
    channel2 := make(chan int)
    done := 0
    sum := 0

    //go subs(channel2)
    go put(channel1, 1)
    go put(channel1, 2)
    go put(channel1, 3)
    go put(channel1, 4)
    go put(channel1, 5)

    for done != 5 {
        select {
        case elem := <-channel1:
            if elem < 0 {
                done++
            } else {
                sum += elem
                fmt.Println(sum)
            }
        case sub := <-channel2:
            sum -= sub
            fmt.Printf("atimta : %d\n", sub)
            fmt.Println(sum)
        }
    }
    close(channel1)
    close(channel2)
}
```