# Do API calls create goroutines?

Tags: go, google-drive-api, gmail-api, google-sheets-api

I was testing things out and noticed that when I made Google API calls, my program would create 2 extra goroutines (went from 1 to 3 goroutines).  I feel like this would lead to a problem where too many goroutines are created.

Comment: Anything can create goroutines. What is "too many goroutines"?

Comment: Come back when you have a few million goroutines and a load average of 1.0. :)

Comment: When our stack space will be filled due to having a bunch of goroutines

Comment: Goroutines are not OS threads. You can have many goroutines on a single thread. Each requires only a few bytes of state. See also [How do goroutines work? (or: goroutines and OS threads relation)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24599645/1068283)

Comment: @developer: The stack limit in go is 1,000,000,000 bytes. It takes a lot of goroutines to hit that, and usually only caused by runaway recursion.

Answer (score 2):

> Do API calls create goroutines?

Not inherently. But many implementations of APIs of course will.

> I was testing things ... my program would create 2 extra goroutines.

Why do you think this is "extra"? It's probably exactly the right number of goroutines.

> I feel like this would lead to a problem where too many goroutines are created.

Don't. You are wrong to feel this way. There's absolutely nothing wrong with using goroutines--that's why they exist.