# question about goroutine infinite loop and memory allocation

Tags: go, memory, goroutine

So i have a program which need to allocate a very big chunk of memory and hold it forever. As a test, i also run a goroutine which runs an infinite loop, in my main thread, i allocate the memory, however the program stuck forever in the goroutine's infinite loop even i set GOMAXPROCS to more then 1.

```
func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(2)
    go func() {
        for {
            //fmt.Printf("goroutine1\n")
        }
    }()
    fmt.Println("main thread1")
    x := [1145][1145]int{}
    for i := 0; i < 1144; i++ {
        fmt.Println(i)
        x[i][i] = i
    }
    fmt.Println("main thread2")

}
```

if i don't do anything in the infinite loop, my main thread1 will never be able to successfully allocate the memory and print "main thread2", even i set GOMAXPROCS to 2, if i print something inside the infinite loop, everythings works fine(which is expected, as the goroutine print something in the infinite loop, it invoke the system call and yield the cpu, so my main thread can allocate the memory.

i am wondering why is that?

Comment: A tight loop like this doesn't give the scheduler the opportunity to run. Basically... never run a tight loop like this.

Comment: A busy loop is always a programming error. There's no reason for it in your code.

Comment: but doesn't set GOMAXPROCS more than 1 means i can have more than 1 core and my main thread will have a chance to run as well?

Comment: Your main goroutine does have a chance to run, until the runtime expects to interrupt the busy loop and is blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Your underlying computer system has some number of thread-executors.  The Go runtime finds out how many on its own, and creates the appropriate number of runtime executors to use all of the system's.  Changing GOMAXPROCS changes how many executors the runtime will try to allocate, but has no effect on the underlying system.  In this case, it appears that the underlying system itself has only one executor.

If your underlying system had two or more, Go would already have created two executors by this point and would be running the infinite loop goroutine on one of them, and your `main` goroutine on the other, at the same time.  But since your system has only one, just one gets to run.  Regardless of how many runtime-level executors the Go runtime might create, only one of them can be bound to a hardware CPU to actually *run*.

Note that goroutines are mapped many-to-N.  For instance, suppose you spin off 1000 goroutines, and have ten CPUs.  The runtime will allocate ten executors and use the ten CPUs to run ten of the 1000 goroutines at once.  The remaining 990 goroutines wait until one of the executors reaches a point where it voluntarily stops running *that* goroutine and picks up one of the remaining 990.

You can call [`runtime.Gosched`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Gosched) yourself, from any goroutine, to say: *I voluntarily suspend myself to let other goroutines that would like to run, run, until an executor can pick me up to run again.*  Many other systems call this function `yield` or some variation.  (And be careful with the word "suspend": I used it here for effect, but the goroutine that caled `runtime.Gosched` is not technically *suspended* in that it's still marked as "would like to run", while other goroutines may be technically suspended in that they're marked "cannot run now, waiting for ____" (fill in the blank).)

See also [How do goroutines work? (or: goroutines and OS threads relation)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24599645/1256452).

Comment: even i run my program on a 4 cores machine, the main thread still can't proceed. I am wondering how can i configure how many system thread-executors i can allocate to my go program?

Comment: [runtime.NumCPU](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#NumCPU) tells you how many processors the Go code counted at startup. Leave `MAXPROCS` unset and you'll have this many concurrent executors available. "Number of cores in the machine" is not necessarily how many *you* can use, as this depends on other things like your OS.